# How can I convert the merge function to be readable on Keras 2.?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a program that it has been written for `Keras 1.x.x` and I am trying to rerun it in `Keras 2.x.x`. However when it reaches to this point,

```
from keras.layers import Input, merge

up2 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

it is showing the following error:

```
UserWarning: The `merge` function is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
  up1 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv3), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
/usr/local/python/3.5.2-gcc4/externalmodules/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py:456: UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
  name=name)
```

I have not changed anything, even data is same. Could you please guide me how can I convert the merge function to be readable on Keras 2.x.x.? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The warning is quit clear. You should use `kears.layers.merge.Concatenate` instead of `merge`.

```
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
up2 = Concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion and it is showing me the following error: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`